# Java Bean Specifications for boolean field

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have Java bean with the field activeRecord

```
private Boolean activeRecord;

@Override
public Boolean isActiveRecord() {
    return activeRecord;
}

@Override
public void setActiveRecord(Boolean activeRecord) {
    this.activeRecord = activeRecord;
}
```

when I send it in **List** as Jasper Report data source

```
List<Branch> dataList = new BranchLogic().selectAll();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList);
```

I get the error message

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: activeRecord.
>   ....
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'activeRecord' has no getter method in class 'class com.tawaak.app.data.domain.model.branch.Branch'

Why Jasper doesn't recognize the `isActiveRecord` as a getter method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prefix `is...` can be used for methods that return a primitive `boolean`. However, your field `activeRecord` is of type `Boolean`, which is an object (the wrapper type of `boolean`), and for objects you always need to use `get...`.

From the [JavaBeans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/), 8.3.2:

> In addition, for `boolean` properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> ```
> public boolean is<PropertyName>();
> ```
>
> This `is<PropertyName>` method may be provided instead of a `get<PropertyName>` method, or it may be provided in addition to a `get<PropertyName>` method.

As such, you have two possible fix:

- Make your `activeRecord` a `boolean` and keep the getter `isActiveRecord()`. This would be the preferred approach if `activeRecord` cannot be `null`.
- Keep it as a `Boolean`, but rename your method `isActiveRecord()` to `getActiveRecord()`. You'll need to make sure the caller handles `null` properly.